# Is congruency same as $*$-congruency for real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, transpose

Two real matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ are said to be congruent to each other if there exists an invertible matrix $P\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $B=P^tAP$, where $P^t$ is the transpose of $P$. Similarly, two complex matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ are said to be $*$-congruent to each other if there exists an invertible matrix $P\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $B=P^{*}AP$, where $P^{*}$ is the conjugate-transpose of $P$. My question is if $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ are $*$-congruent as matrices over $\mathbb C$, must they be congruent to each other?

Comment: Yes: Dragomir Ž. Doković and Khakim Ikramov, [On the congruence of square real matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379502003002?via%3Dihub), September 2002, Linear Algebra and its Applications, 353(1):149-158

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @sagnik This can also be proved as a direct consequence of [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think about it. Actually i am only familiar with Sylvester's law of inertia for real matrices. But it seems that the complex version answers my question.

Comment: Wait, isn't Sylvester's law of inertia only applicable to real symmetric matrices?